# few lines of code in python does not run or takes long time to run. Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I tried to run it, but only colaboratory did it after loading for a while

```
greetme = {'fr' : 'bonjour', 'en' : 'hi', 'es' : 'hola'}
for language, greeting in greetme.items():
    language = input('What is your preferred language? ')
    if language in greetme:
        print(greetme[language])
        break
    else:
        print('selection not in database, try again')
        continue
```

Comment: Give a sample input which would make this easier to reproduce

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Right now it only runs at most N-times where N is the size of the dictionary, `greetme`. If it hits a word it has seen, it exits. I don't see why this would either not run or take a long time to run

Comment: i tried the same snippet and it worked perfectly fine for me. Could you show us why isn't working for you? I mean your run log etc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're missing the entire point of dictionaries - you don't need to loop over every item to find a specific one, you can simply ask if it's in the dict, or directly access it by key.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified your code

```
greetme = {'fr' : 'bonjour', 'en' : 'hi', 'es' : 'hola'}

for greeting in greetme:
    language = input('What is your preferred language? ')
    if language in greetme:
        print(greetme[language])
    else:
        print('selection not in database, try again')
```